# Get tagged videos from vimeo

Tags: video, vimeo-api

I need to create a video page based on Vimeo. I fond that using the API I can get all the videos from a channel in my Vimeo account, but I'm trying to get the "related videos" (aka videos sharing the same tags) but there's no way to search for a specific tag within my channel.
Getting all videos and then looping until I find the tags will be cumbersome in a scenario where there are up to 700 videos.
Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not currently a solution. Vimeo plans on adding tag filters to every videos endpoint, but there currently is no timeframe.